# quadratic formula roots(a,b,c) function. python

Tags: python, formula, quadratic

I don't get any error messages, but my code doesn't print the x values.

```
    from math import sqrt
a= float(input("a= "))
b= float(input("b= "))
c= float(input("c= "))
def roots(a,b,c):
    disc = b**2 - 4*a*c
    if disc >= 0:
        return ("x= ",(-b + sqrt(disc))/(2*a), "x= ",(-b - sqrt(disc))/(2*a))
    if disc < 0:
        return ("x= ",-b/(2*a),"+",sqrt(disc*(-1))/(2*a),"i" \
                "x= ",-b/(2*a),"-",sqrt(disc*(-1))/(2*a),"i")
    print(roots(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: You input a, b, and c, and you define a function called `roots`, and that's it.  If you want the code in `roots` to be executed, you have to *call* the function.  The only call to `roots` is from within `roots` itself, after the returns.  Move it outside of the function.

Comment: you're not calling `roots`. Remove that tab before `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You have indented `print(roots(a,b,c))`. This line should be at zero indentation since this is not part of the function definition -you are calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt
a= float(input("a= "))
b= float(input("b= "))
c= float(input("c= "))
def roots(a,b,c):
    disc = b**2 - 4*a*c
    if disc >= 0:
        return ("x= ",(-b + sqrt(disc))/(2*a), "x= ",(-b - sqrt(disc))/(2*a))
    if disc < 0:
        return ("x= ",-b/(2*a),"+",sqrt(disc*(-1))/(2*a),"i" \
                "x= ",-b/(2*a),"-",sqrt(disc*(-1))/(2*a),"i")
print(roots(a,b,c))
```

Properly indent your code and you will get your answer.

Comment: It worked, thanks. But since i have complex numbers in some solutions how do i perform a unittest?

Comment: if you want to perform more complex arithmetic calculation with real, imaginary or complex numbers then you should use http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/introduction.html package